# How to extract MAC and AES keys using x9.63 based kdf

Tags: key-derivation, ecies

For trying ECIES, I need to derive keys for MAC and AES from the shared secret using ANSI x9.63 based KDF. The information on key derivation I got it from Section 3.6.1 of http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf.

What is the standard procedure to extract/separate the keys for MAC and AES from the Key derived using KDF?

Answer (score 1):

For that standard, it is covered in Section 5.1.3:

> 5. Use the key derivation function KDF established during the setup procedure to generate keying data K of length enckeylen + mackeylen
>      octets from Z and [SharedInfo1 ]. If the key derivation function
>      outputs “invalid”, output “invalid” and stop.
> 6. Parse the leftmost enckeylen octets of K as an encryption key EK and the rightmost mackeylen octets of K as a MAC key MK. If symmetric
>      encryption method is XOR and backwards compatibility mode is not
>      selected, then instead parse the rightmost enckeylen octets of K as an
>      encryption key EK and the leftmost mackeylen octets of K as a MAC key
>      MK.

In the end, it depends on the parameters `enckeylen` and `mackeylen`, which define the sizes of the keys for the symmetric encryption and the MAC, respectively.

Comment: OK an ugly way to perform the key derivation, but quoting the standard is never wrong.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes What would be a pretty way?

Comment: Different labels for different keys would be nice. I'm also kind of flabbergasted why a good KDF needs a different order of keys for different schemes. There is talk about the KDF outputting "invalid" which seems strange to me; KDF's generally should work for most input / output sizes and almost any kind of data. There is talk about "parsing" key octets; there is really nothing to parse: parsing assumes that the input data has some kind of syntax / semantics while a KDF should generally output random data. So... quite a lot actually. Nothing serious but definitely "ugly" in my opinion.